# How to supress pop up window?

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer

I wrote a simple script below and it works unless I purposely put in an incorrect password. If that happens, a popup window comes up saying auth error. How can I simply catch all errors and deal with them, instead of a popup waiting for manual intervention? The `try..catch` below does not work.

EDIT: Also the return value has no value. When I echo it out, its blank.. Has anyone had luck getting an actual return value and if so what is a success value?

```
$username = "whomever"
$password = "test1234"

$ie=New-Object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.Visible = $false
$ie.Silent = $true

$requestUri = "www.doesnotmatter.com"
try
{
    $return_val = $ie.Navigate($requestUri)
    echo "return is $return_val"

    while($ie.busy)
    {
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
    }
}
catch
{
    $err = $_.Exception
    echo "Error is: $err"
}
finally
{
   echo "out"
}
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce - you're not even using the password in the sample code?

Comment: Yes the password is being used. When I set the correct values for username and password, I don't get the error. When I change the password to something incorrect, then I get the auth error.

Comment: I guess I'm blind because I just can't see where the username/password is being used in the sample.

Comment: Not blind. I don't seem to understand either. But..when pass is correct the auth error popup does not happen. Somehow the navigate command is using the username and pass.